# MapView Changes Region Automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm a beginner and have created a small project just to learn about mapview in which I set four button up down right left and set a airplane image at center like this

[image]

when we click on the up button the lattitude increases by 10 coordinates like 47->57->67 till 77 in in down like->-43->-53->-63 till -73 and same for left and right I only want to know that why it is changing the region and zoom out when I go up (when increase the lattitude) and zoom in (when decrease the lattitude) and how to fix it except that everything is working fine.

I'll put code for one button lets say **UP** for your better understanding:-

1.in viewDidLoad

```
 lattitude=27;
```

2.in my viewController.m

```
- (IBAction)up:(id)sender {
    if (lattitude<=70) {

    _targetOutlet.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"up"];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    lattitude=lattitude+10;

    centre=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lattitude, longitude);
    map.userLocation.coordinate=centre;
        region=[map regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centre, zoomScale ,zoomScale)];

            [map setRegion:[map regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
    }];

    }


        NSLog(@"UP = Lattitude = %f longitude= %f",lattitude,longitude);

}
```

> Note: The region is fixed in the entire project.

Comment: can you please elaborate more when it is changing region and zoom ?

Comment: its hard to explain but its like when we click on up button the mapView zoom out and when we click on down button the mapView zoom in its changing the region.. @vaibhav

Comment: whats the `zoomScale` here ?

Comment: zoomScale is an CLLocationDistance that i set at zoomScale=5000000 in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

probably the problem is in you `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` method where every time you are setting the `latitudinalMeters` `longitudinalMeters` parameters of this method.

```
 MKCoordinateRegion MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance ( CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate, CLLocationDistance latitudinalMeters, CLLocationDistance longitudinalMeters );
```

You can try this one:

```
region=[map regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centre, 200 ,200)];
```

or see [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance) for more info :)

Comment: and the problem is if you want to find the answer u cant have it without implementing it.